# Missing or invalid signature in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode8

I have not found any functional solution, between a great number of suggestion on internet. I don't know exactly where and when it stopped to work, but I have an app at Apple Store that is working fine and it is in the 1.7 version. One month ago, I have tried to implement Push Notification and, to this tool works, I have to create and manipulate some certificates (Apple Developer certificates, Keychain Access, etc). After that, when I try to upload a new version to Apple Store using Xcode, I receive the message “Upload Successful”. Some minutes after this, I receive this message in my email:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "Habilidades Médicas". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>
> ***Missing or invalid signature -*** 
>   ***The bundle 'com.IvanSinigagliaApps.ChkList' at bundle path 'Payload/HabMed.app' is not signed using an Apple submission certificate.***
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary. Regards, The App Store team”

I really don`t know what I did. Maybe, I can have deleted a key (keychain) or deleted a certificate or both. All the posts I have found about “Missing or Invalid Signature” didn’t work for me; many don't push me to my issue and many other are out of date for Xcode 8.3. I will post some screens with some doubts I have to show most information I can and I hope they can work as clues to help me to fix it.

Fig 01: My Keychain Access: I can found to Certificates: 1) iPhone Developer: QRL…, and 2) iPhone Distribution: C3D….

[image]

Fig 02: Apple Developer Provisioning Profiles:

[image]

Fig 03: iOs Certificates

[image]

Fig 04: Xcode (Certificate iPhone Developer QRL… ) ???

[image]

Fig 05: Xcode: even when manual provisioning is set up (C3D…) it doesn’t work.

[image]

Fig 06: Uploading App (Signing identity Distribution C3D…

[image]

Fig 07: Uploading (C3D…)

[image]

Fig 08: Upload Successful

[image]

UPDATE #1
This is happening the same way to my 4 apps, that were loading fine before.

Still not working, but after following the instructions at Apple Developer Troubleshotings technical Note TN2318, section: Resolving Signature Verification Failure, I run the Terminal with these instructions:

`codesign --verify -vvvv -R='anchor apple generic and certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.1] exists and (certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2] exists or certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4] exists)' /path/to/the.app`

I receive this message: `code object is not signed at all`

[image]

Now, I will try to go on this clue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is done, after a lot of hard work.
I have a great help from Apple Developer technical Support and to short this issue what I did was trying to fix it editing my certificates. As the problems involved all my apps, it should be something with the certificates. So, the guy from Apple, John, told me to think about this information:

> I see they were issuing an revoking their certificates throughout May
>   and created the latest Certificate on June 1st. It is currently the
>   only active certificate. When a Distribution/Development Cert is
>   revoked, the associated provisioning profiles are invalidated and the
>   apps will stop functioning. This is the expected behavior. Apps
>   distributed via the App Store are not subject to this behavior. Only
>   apps distributed using the Ad-Hoc distribution method.

So I went to my certificates, at Apple Developer site, and edited those that I had just revoked and edited them again. A new one was created for this particular app and I have downloaded it to my machine. I have done a new upload and now everything is working fine again, with all apps.

There was a big confusion with all my certificates and with all my apps that. This confusion came to create this issue. Now I have reorganized all this stuff and everything is fine.

That's my lesson from this issue: keep all your work organized.

I really hope someone with the same issue can fix them after reading all this post or at least find an orientation.

Thank you Apple Developer Support and everybody who has read this.